# How to replace all documents with new documents efficiently

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to replace all documents in my collection and replace them with new documents.

So far, I tried using deleteMany() then create() but there seems to be a small latency between the 2 operations. So is there any way I can delete everything and create documents at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You might try `replaceMany`; since that's an atomic operation, it's considered as a single operation without any latency between deleting the old documents and creating the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the old object IDs, the replace or update method will be the solution. If not - delete and then сreate. Also you can combine it all in BulkWrite method.